# ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, gwt

for both ways I can specify values for contextConfigLocation simply by separating them by commas. Does it matter if I have one file with all beans in it oder several files with all my beans? Or maybe have several files, importing into one main file and including only this?
Im asking because we have Problems with a GWT Spring combination. We have action classes annotated for component scanning. But during some test on different machines, for example on my machine works everything fine, but on my colleagues machine it fails. He has to specify the actions in the xml

```
<bean>...</bean>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too work with GWT-Spring configuration and I have never had an issue like this . It's your decision to use a single file or different config files . Maybe your friend has a configuration issue or he's using an older version of Spring dependency where component scan doesn't work .

I don't think it has anything to do with how you detect your Spring beans.

Comment: We work with svn and maven. We checked several times our project configuration. It should be the same..

Comment: @mephi do a mvn eclipse:eclipse , refresh the project and check the .classpath files in both the machines . If these are similar , you may want to check on the libraries in eclipse.

Comment: It seemed I found the problem. In a basic component were placeholders getting replaced was a call like "appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/somepackages/util/config/beans.xml");" opening a new context which isnt accessible from the context of the dispatcherservlet but from the context of the contextloaderlistener. But I wonder why it worked on my machine. Now I repoduced the error..

Comment: Whats happens during the call appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/somepackages/util/config/beans.xml"); ?

Comment: Is the AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext able to access the context of the DispatcherServlet?

Comment: @mephi The dispatcher-servlet application context can see the beans of the root web application context but not vice-verse . The contextLoaderListener creates the root web application context . If you create a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or xmlwebapplicationcontext  , the configs will be loaded again . If you make your controller ApplicationContextAware, probably you can 'see' the dispatcher servlet's application context .

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between this both ways of defining the beans for the context.

Both ways the result is one spring-context with all the beans form the different files.